# C++ Clases, variable is always different from the actual number

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass

I'm trying to make a text based turn based rpg for which i wanted to have different classes with different ranges of stats. One problem I keep running into is that i cannot print the random number I obtained outside of where I get my number. If i do it just gives me a new one instead of my previous number.

````
Filename: Finalh.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// Base class
class Base {
public:
    int newATK, newHP,answer,player;
    int  ATK, HP;
};

// Derived class
class Thief : public Base {
public:
    int HP = rand() % (80 + 1 - 60) + 60;
    int ATK = rand() % (40 + 1 - 20) + 20;
};


Filename: Final.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Finalh.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));
    int answer;

    cout << "Choose your fighter  1) Assassin    2) Tank    3) Knight" << endl;
    cin >> answer;
    
    if (answer == 1)
    {
        Thief player;
        cout << "You have choosen assassin, he has HP " << player.HP << " and ATK " << player.ATK 
        << endl;
        player.newHP = player.HP;
    }
    
    cout << "Press 1 to show HP" << endl;
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == 1)
    {
            Thief player;
            cout << "This is my HP " << player.HP << endl;
            cout << "This is my HP " << player.newHP << endl;
    }
}```
````

Comment: You redeclare your Your HP and ATK variables in `Theif`

Comment: `Thief player;`  you create a new instance that has a lifetime that ends when the if () {} ends

Comment: Your big problem is understanding variable scope and lifetime.

Answer (score 0):

drescherjm was right, the value got lost due to the instance life running out the moment I closed the if. The solution was just passing the value to a variable and then printing that variable:

```
newHP = player.HP;
newATK = player.ATK;
cout << "You have choosen assassin, he has HP " <<  newHP << " and ATK " << newATK << endl;
```